# ScalaTest and IntelliJ - Running one Test at a time

Tags: intellij-idea, scalatest

I have a ScalaTest which extends the FlatSpec. I have many tests inside the test and I now want to have the possibility to run one test at a time. No matter what I do, I can't get IntelliJ to do it. In the Edit Configurations of the test, I can specify that it should run one test at a time by giving the name of the test. For example:

```
it should "test the sample multiple times" in new MyDataHelper {
  ...
}
```

where I gave the name as "test the sample multiple times", but it does not seem to take that and all I get to see is that it just prints Empty Test Suite. Any ideas how can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An approach that works for me is to right-click (on Windows) within the definition of the test, and choose "Run MyTestClass..." -- or, equivalently, Ctrl-Shift-F10 with the cursor already inside the test. But it's a little delicate and your specific example may be causing your problem. Consider:

```
class MyTestClass extends FlatSpec with Matchers {

  "bob" should "do something" in  {
    // ...
  }

  it should "do something else" in  {
    // ...
  }

  "fred" should "do something" in  {
    // ...
  }

  it should "do something else" in  {
    // ...
  }
}
```

I can use the above approach to run any of the four tests individually. Your approach based on editing configurations works too. But if I delete the first test I can't run the second one individually -- the others are still fine. That's because a test that starts with `it` is intended to follow one that doesn't -- then the `it` is replaced with the appropriate string in the name of the test.

If you want to run the tests by setting up configurations, then the names of these four tests are:

- bob should do something
- bob should do something else
- fred should do something
- fred should do something else

Again, note the substitution for `it` -- there's no way to figure out the name of a test starting with `it` if it doesn't follow another test.

I'm using IntelliJ Idea 13.1.4 on Windows with Scala 2.10.4, Scala plugin 0.41.1, and ScalaTest 2.1.0. I wouldn't be surprised if this worked less well in earlier versions of Idea or the plugin.

Answer (score 2):

If using Gradle, go to `Preferences > Build, Execution, Deployment > Build Tools > Gradle` and in the `Build and run > Run tests using:` section, select `IntelliJ IDEA` if you haven't already.

Answer (score 0):

I just realized that I'm able to run individual tests with IntelliJ 13.1.3 Community Edition. With the one that I had earlier 13.0.x, it was unfortunately not possible.